# How to coat gummies with beeswax/carnauba wax and coconut oil/palm oil?

Tags: baking

I tried coating my gummies with beeswax but it was a failure. First, I melted beeswax and tried to pour it in a spray bottle but it hardened so fast. Also, I tried coating them by just putting them in the beeswax but the gummies dissolved with the wax because of the heat. I tried to coat them with a mix of olive oil and wax (2/3+1/3) but it wasn't perfect, there were some little pieces of wax on the gummies.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, the way waxy coatings are applied is actually by adding your candies and powdered wax to a tumbler.

Claire from "Bon Appetit" tried to accomplish it by abusing a salad spinner to make gourmet jelly beans and M&Ms. Ann Reardon from "How to Cook That" used a children's toy rock tumbler to apply a cocoa butter coating to some jelly beans.

[Claire's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvDj7DF1jsk&ab_channel=BonApp%C3%A9tit)

[Ann Reardon's video](https://youtu.be/Vn8-p_Gi2fU)

Comment: thank you but jelly coating is different from gummy coating.

Comment: Would you describe the difference please? As far as I knew the only difference was textural? I hear the words interchangeably really.